Optimize memory use of Python function
Updated
I have the following function, which is used in a spatial statistical model. I'm able to run the model on a subset of my data (1 US state) using a few GB of RAM, but it runs out of memory when I extend it to the full US.
I've made multiple adjustments from the original function. As much as possible, I use sparse representations and methods designed for sparse matrices. The input matrix A is 207972 x 207972 and has 1314488 non-zero elements, or about 0.003%. Testing the full dataset on a cluster and using 500 GB of RAM (tried up to 750 GB), the code runs to Sigma = spsolve(Q_perturbed, b).astype(np.float32) before running out of memory. I can save memory by using int16, etc. because most elements are ones, but my understanding is that will add overhead because Python will convert to float32 to ensure everything has the same data type when performing some operations.
I only need to run the function once to get a number, then I can use that number as a fixed input to my model. It is getting stuck at spsolve, despite the fact the function uses sparse matrices. My understanding is this function may generate dense intermediate matrices. I tried both csc and csr representations - csr was recommended as more efficient. I'm also now running the process for each column in a loop using 60 GB of RAM to avoid the RAM issue. However, it is very slow - i.e., hasn't finished 10,000 columns (about 5%) after about 20 minutes. I'd also tried running with a much larger RAM allocation of 1 TB with the non-loop method and ran out of memory. The cluster can handle up to 2 TB of RAM, but I think it would take a week to start up. I looked at a few other solutions that change the solver from spsolve().
from scipy.sparse import diags, identity, csc_matrix
from scipy.linalg import solve
from scipy.sparse.linalg import spsolve
def blockwise_solve(Q_perturbed, b):
    """
    Solve the system Q_perturbed * x = b using block-wise solving,
    where each column of b represents a separate right-hand side.
    """
    n = Q_perturbed.shape[0]
    solutions = []

    # Iterate over columns of b (each column is a separate right-hand side)
    for i in range(b.shape[1]):
        if i%10**4==0:
            logging.info(i)
            print(i)
        rhs = b[:, i].toarray().flatten()  # Convert column to 1D array
        solution = spsolve(Q_perturbed, rhs, use_umfpack=True)  # Solve for this right-hand side
        solutions.append(solution)

    # Combine solutions into a matrix
    return np.vstack(solutions).T  # Return the solutions as a matrix, one solution per column

def scaling_factor_sp(A):
    """Compute the scaling factor from an adjacency matrix.
    This function uses sparse matrix computations and is most
    efficient on sparse adjacency matrices. Used in the BYM2 model.
    The scaling factor is a measure of the variance in the number of
    edges across nodes in a connected graph.
    Only works for fully connected graphs. The argument for scaling
    factors is developed by Andrea Riebler, Sigrunn H. Sørbye,
    Daniel Simpson, Havard Rue in "An intuitive Bayesian spatial
    model for disease mapping that accounts for scaling"
    https://arxiv.org/abs/1601.01180"""

    # Computes the precision matrix in sparse format.
    num_neighbors = A.sum(axis=1).A.ravel().astype(np.float32)
    D = diags(num_neighbors, format="csc", dtype=np.float32) # Degree matrix
    del num_neighbors
    Q = D - A # Precision matrix
    del D
    del A
    
    # add a small jitter along the diagonal
    jitter = max(Q.diagonal()) * np.sqrt(np.finfo(np.float32).eps)
    Q_perturbed = Q + diags(np.ones(Q.shape[0]) * jitter, dtype=np.float32, format="csc")
    del jitter
    del Q
    # Compute a version of the pseudo-inverse

    n = Q_perturbed.shape[0]
    # b = identity(n, dtype=np.int8, format="csc")
    b = identity(n, format="csc").astype(np.float32)
    gc.collect()
    Q_perturbed = Q_perturbed.tocsr()
    # Solve the system using block-wise solving
    Sigma = blockwise_solve(Q_perturbed, b)

    del Q_perturbed
    del b
    gc.collect()
    
    W = Sigma.dot(np.ones(Sigma.shape[0], dtype=np.float32))
    Q_inv = Sigma - (W[:, np.newaxis] * W[np.newaxis, :]) / W.sum()
    del W
    del Sigma
    gc.collect()
    
    # Compute the geometric mean of the diagonal on a
    # precision matrix.

    return np.exp(np.sum(np.log(Q_inv.diagonal())) / Q_inv.shape[0])

scaling_factor = scaling_factor_sp(adj_matrix)

Outputs using full dataset.
    2024-11-08 10:47:23,524 - INFO - After running Q Memory Usage: 171.34 MB
2024-11-08 10:47:23,552 - INFO - After running Q_perturbed Memory Usage: 179.16 MB
2024-11-08 10:47:23,553 - INFO - After running b Memory Usage: 179.16 MB
2024-11-08 10:47:23,553 - INFO - Sparsity of Q_perturbed: 0.0035%


Having the output or realistic inputs so to run it would help a bit to know if the problem is only spsolve or also previous lines. Maybe it creates a dense matrix? Is Q_perturbed a sparse matrix?

i would recommend you del variables as soon as possible to free their memory once they are no-longer needed.

Good comments! I've updated the post with output details.
